# Intent.putExtra() prompts the wrong third party app

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm migrating the code from `Intent.setDataAndType()` to `Intent.putExtra()`, but I can't get the same result.

I'm also handling the data differently for android N than for the rest of the OS levels.

Here's my code:

```
// coming to this method
final FileType fileType
final File file;

final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(MyApplication.getAppContext(), MyApplication.getAppContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file));
    //intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(MyApplication.getAppContext(), MyApplication.getAppContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file), fileType.getMimeType());
} else {
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, Uri.fromFile(file));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, fileType.getMimeType());
    //intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), fileType.getMimeType());
}

startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that this is trying to open the wrong application, regardless of the file type I send.
For example, this wants to open the calendar or settings for opening PDF files.

If I use the `Intent.setDataAndType()` the data is sent correctly to the correct application, but I get an `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException` exception on large data sets.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Here's what I'm trying to achieve. I download a file from the network (txt, html, pdf...), I save the file locally and then I want to open/read that file within the device's default reader for that file type. If the user hasn't selected a reader for that file type the user will be prompt with the android default prompt to select an app that can read this file.
If the user does not have an app to read this file type, we just display a message saying the file cannot be opened on this device.

Comment: Please start your post by explaining what you have and what you want to achieve. This is pretty vague in this way. Give a decent introduction please.

Comment: done. let me know if that helps.

Comment: Can you do what you want with `setDataAndType()`? If so, why are you trying to use `putExtra()` instead?

Comment: With the set data we're sending the data of the file to the third party app. Since this can throw an exception, I believe I need to pass the location of the file to be opened in the third party app

Comment: You have told nothing about large data sets in your introduction. And that was not an introduction but a post scriptum. I cannot folow you. You are not even mentioning the use of a file provider.  I dont understand your problem. I have to give up.

Comment: ?? OK...(??) The size of the data set is irrelevant. Why? Because some files are a 1 line text files, while others are 30 page pdf files with images. You don't have to comment on this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to use `setData()` as `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` only applies to the URI set with `setData()` or those added via `setClipData()` - note that the type is automatically provided for you by `FileProvider`.

As per the [EXTRA_INTENT documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_INTENT), that extra must only contain an `Intent` object and is only used for `ACTION_CHOOSER`.